# Is it possible for SQL Statement to group it with the added suggested_phrase column base on near or matching each words in the same list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, vb.net-2010, visual-foxpro

Is it possible for SQL Statement to group it with the added suggested_phrase column base on near or matching each words in the same list / column ?

Objective:
1. Auto suggest phrase base on matching keywords.
2. 100% each word of phrase_words would be match or present in the suggested_phrase
3. Ignoring non-alphanumeric character (only if possible, not required)

```
Table_1 list
row_id   | Phrase_words
1        | [Humpty Dumpty sat]
2        | on a wall humpty+dumpty
3        | Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall
4        | Dumpty, Humpty, wall, sat
5        | Ben Cater
6        | Engr. Benedic
7        | Engr. Benedic Cater
8        | Engr. Cater
9        | Dr. Cater
```

The result I would like to see

```
Table_1 list with suggested_phrase
row_id   | Phrase_words                  | Suggested_Phrase
1        | [Humpty Dumpty sat]           | Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall
2        | on a wall humpty dumpty       | Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall
3        | Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall   | Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall
4        | Dumpty, Humpty, wall, sat     | Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall
5        | Ben Cater                     | Engr. Benedic Cater
6        | Engr. Benedic                 | Engr. Benedic Cater
7        | Engr. Benedic Cater           | Engr. Benedic Cater
8        | Engr. Cater                   | Engr. Benedic Cater
9        | Dr. Cater                     | Dr. Cater
```

Comment: The SQL language is not ideal for text parsing. There are far better options for such an application.

Comment: If this would be done on VFP client side, then you could do that with a UDF (User Defined Function), however that might be slow for a large table (for a large table you might as well create a CLR UDF for SQL Server - string operations are much faster with a CLR function).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it and will end up with lots of CASE statements ;

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN phrase_words like '%humpty%' AND phrase_words like '%dumpty%'
        THEN 'Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall'
     WHEN phrase_words like '%Engr. Benedic%' OR phrase_words like '%Ben Cater%' OR 
phrase_words LIKE '%Engr. Cater%'
        THEN 'Engr. Benedic Cater'
     WHEN phrase_words like '%Dr. Cater%'
        THEN 'Dr. Cater'
END Suggested_Phrase
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: What I need is to make it auto suggest, I have 100 thousand row lines in the list and it is changing every month. Your code will not work.

Comment: @BenedicCater SQL cannot auto suggest, it's a rule based platform unlike ML/AI

Comment: If you have a list of suggestions, then join it to the base table ex: LEFT JOIN suggestions ON Suggested_Phrase.phrase_works LIKE CONCAT('%', suggestions.column,'%')